# displaying a simple image in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

- I have a image called `image.jpg` stored in location
  `/public/images/images.jpg` in the express folder

**My express program is below ::**

```
var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http')
  , mysql = require('mysql'); // <---- HERE

var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: "root",
    database: 'test123'
});

connection.connect(); // <---- AND HERE

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 7005);


app.get('/',function(request,response){
connection.query('SELECT * FROM MyTable', function(err, rows, fields)

    {
            console.log('Connection result error '+err);
            console.log('no of records is '+rows.length);
                    response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
            response.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
    });

} );



http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

**I am not able to display the image from the locaton where i have stored when i give**

```
http://54.218.73.244:7005/image.jpg
```

Where am i going wrong with my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express does not handle serving assets or static files. However, the `static()` middleware was written for this purpose. Just add this line of code:

```
app.use(express.static('/public/images'));
```

This middleware will start a static file server mounted to `/`, and will serve files from the `/public/images` directory. Accessing `http://url.ext/image.jpg` will serve the image file from `/public/images/image.jpg`.

Comment: Your solution and guidance works ... thanks for such a nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

you can use the express.static built-in middleware function:

```
app.use(express.static('images'));
```

or

```
app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/images'));
```

to use the absolute path of the directory that you want to serve

Answer (score -1):

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/img'));
```

Comment: The only thing this "new" answer does is to repeat what half of the other answers are already saying, including the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18908601/14267427).